LeetCode: Climbing Stairs
I've tried to solve the LeetCode 70.Climbing Stairs. I know, it is same as fibonaci, but I've wanted to try a different solution for this. Here is the problem:
You are climbing a staircase. It takes n steps to reach the top.
Each time you can either climb 1 or 2 steps. In how many distinct ways can you climb to the top?
Example 1:
Input: n = 2
Output: 2
Explanation: There are two ways to climb to the top.

1 step + 1 step
2 steps

Example 2:
Input: n = 3
Output: 3
Explanation: There are three ways to climb to the top.

1 step + 1 step + 1 step
1 step + 2 steps
2 steps + 1 step

I used static because the result must be the count, so, declaring it static, it won't be initialized every time I call recursively my function. Here is my code:
int climbStairs(int n) {
    static int count = 0;
    if (n == 2) {
        count = count + 2;
        return count;
    }
    if (n == 1) {
        count = count + 1;
        return count;
    }
    climbStairs(n-1);
    climbStairs(n-2);
    return count;
}

When I tried to run in LeetCode, only one case passed, but when I tried using terminal on my computer, all was fine. I don't understand what's the problem. Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

static variable is initialized only 1 time in leetcode, so old value is reused for subsequent tests and thus screws the result

Please let us know what the problem is, which test cases failed. If you do not know the secret test cases let us know which test cases you invented yourself, because that will allow to spot the gap in your thinking. Provide a [mre] which applies your test cases. Do not forget to define the expected results of the test cases.

Please [edit] and add your complete test code with your test cases as [mcve]

Solve it without static. Does that work for you in LeetCode?

There's no need for the static variable. Just return the count from the current level and below, and the caller can add the results from the recursive calls and return that.

I.e. instead of count = count + 2; return count; just do return 2;

Why are you throwing away the return value of the recursive calls to climbStairs?  Maybe you should add those to count; that way you don't have to make it static (actually, you don't need it at all).

Remember, each time you use a static variable, a kitten dies.

"but I've wanted to try a different solution for this." There can be NO different solution for this. Since the answer is a Fibonacci number, any correct solution computes Fibonacci numbers, nothing more, nothing less. Might as well choose a good one.
